# PowerShell: Remove domain extensions in email list

Tags: powershell, csv, email, dns

I'v got this list of email addresses.
I would like to remove all domain extensions.

**Input.csv**
john@email.com
albert@mail.co.uk
al@hotmail.nl
commadore@gmail.al

Should result in:

**Output.csv**
john@email
albert@mail
al@hotmail
commadore@gmail

If I use this code...

```
$Sourcefile = 'C:\PS\Input.csv'
$Output =  'C:\PS\Output.csv'

(Get-Content $Sourcefile) | Foreach-Object {
$_ -replace '.com', ''`
   -replace '.co.uk', ''`
   -replace '.nl', ''`
   -replace '.al', ''

} | Set-Content $Output
```

.. I get:
**Output.csv**
john@email
bert@mail - (**al** is removed)
al@hotmail
madore@gmail - (**com** is removed)

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fairy points out you need to be aware of your regex meta characters like `.`

> I would like to remove all domain extensions.

If that is the case then you should not need to be typing in each one that you want to remove. You should be able to remove all character after and including the last period.

Since `-replace` is an array operator you don't *need* to use `ForEach-Object`

```
(Get-Content $Sourcefile) -replace "(@.+?)\..*$",'$1' | Set-Content $Output
```

That will match everything after and including the "@". It replaces that with just the "@" and what is before the first period.

If you really want to replace certain domains they you might be better off keeping a string array and building a regex replacement string with that. Makes it easier to make changes and the code will stay clean.

```
$suffixesToRemove = "com","co.uk","nl","al"
$regex = "\.($(($suffixesToRemove|ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))$"
(Get-Content $Sourcefile) -replace $regex | Set-Content $Output
```

The computed regex string would look like this

```
\.(com|co\.uk|nl|al)$
```

So it uses a alternating group with meta-charaters escaped.

Comment: Thanks! :) Super happy :)

Answer (score 2):

The `-replace` function uses regular expressions. In RegEx a dot means **any character except newline**. You simply need to escape your dots with `\` to make it work.

Like this:

```
(Get-Content $Sourcefile) | Foreach-Object {
$_ -replace '\.com$', ''`
   -replace '\.co\.uk$', ''`
   -replace '\.nl$', ''`
   -replace '\.al$', ''

} | Set-Content $Output
```

---

As per @gvee's comment adding a end-of-line anchor `$` should make it work even if `some.alternate@emailaddress.com` is supplied.

Comment: Won't this approach fail in a number of scenarios e.g. `some.alternate@emailaddress.com` => `someternate@emailaddress`

Comment: Yes it will. The thing is tough that regexing email addresses is hard. And I am pretty sure that telling OP that they are dealing with RegEx will point them in the right direction.

Comment: @gvee Well I derped. A simple `$` should fix you scenario.